# CanCan and polymorphic class Not Authorized to Access this page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, polymorphic-associations, cancancan

I have an issue with the CanCan Abilities for a polymorphic model called Notes.  Users can add notes to current clients and prospective employees.  Everyone can access the current clients, but only the hiring team can view prospective employees.
The problem is with

```
cannot :manage, Recruit
```

in the ability file for staff, they are suddenly unable to add notes to the Clients they have access to.
Code for Notes association in recruit.rb and client.rb class:

```
has_many :notes, -> { order "notes.updated_at DESC" }, as: :noteable, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => :all_blank, allow_destroy:true
```

notes_controller.rb

```
load_and_authorize_resource :recruit
load_and_authorize_resource :client
load_and_authorize_resource :note, :through => [:recruit, :client]
```

ability.rb

```
if user.has_role? :staff
  can :manage, :all
  cannot :manage, Recruit
end

if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
end
```

No one else has this error as far as I can tell.  It's an interesting behavior.  The app won't authorize any notes because the user doesn't have permission to add notes on all models notes are addable to.

edit:

Things I have tried, and failed.

notes_controller.rb:
remove `load_and_authorize :recruit` and `through => :recruit`
This lets staff add notes to their accessible models, but removes the ability for admins to add notes to recruits.

ability.rb:
Adding in `can :manage, Note, noteable_type: 'Recruit'` to the admin part of the file doesn't restore this ability.

Comment: without upload ability.rb it's hard to trace the problem

Comment: updated to add more of ability.rb